# Detect if rotated rectangle is in canvas arc

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a rectangle I've rotated via [`ctx.rotate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/rotate) and an arc.  I want to check to see if any part of the rectangle is inside said arc.  For instance, this should be true:

[image: Arc overlaps rectangle]

I've tried to use [`isPointInPath`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/isPointInPath) but the "point" I'm looking for is not the actual coordinates of the rectangle, but the non-rotated ones (Actual is green, `isPointInPath` is checking against blue):

[image: isPointInPath misses the point]

Here's the JS:

```
var canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas'),
    height = canvas.height = canvas.clientHeight,
    width = canvas.width = canvas.clientWidth,
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = canvas.height = 512;

var shipx = 400,
    shipy = 256;

function moveShip() {
    ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(shipx, shipy);
    ctx.rotate(3.66);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 80, 20);
    ctx.restore();

    // This is what isPointInPath is seeing
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,255,0.5)';
    ctx.fillRect(shipx, shipy, 80, 20);

    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255,0,0,0.5)';
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(256, 256);
    ctx.arc(256, 256, 100, -20 * Math.PI / 180, 90 * Math.PI / 180);
    ctx.lineTo(256, 256);

    if (ctx.isPointInPath(shipx, shipy) || ctx.isPointInPath(shipx + 20, shipy + 20)) {
        // This *should* trigger
        ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,255,0.5)';
    };

    ctx.fill();
}

moveShip();
```

[JSBin for live code fun](http://jsbin.com/lolaro/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Im preparing an answer for you

Comment: IMHO this problem cannot be solved by Canvas API means. `isPointInPath` deal with single point whereas you have set of points (furthermore, rotated). Have you considered using math? It seems more suitable for such problem.

Comment: @hindmost Math is a perfectly viable answer - I'm just not very good at it.  High school was a long time ago...

Comment: I can't solve this problem for you. However I can give some clue. Try get a look at [inequalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_%28mathematics%29). AFAIR that's a thing you needed. First of all you have to compose equations for the arc's and rectangle's outlines, then somehow transform them into a set of inequalities. That's all I can remember now (I'm not a math guru too, though I have math education:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use coordinate rotation to align the rectangle with the system, then just use one of the many axis-aligned algos for your case:

```
var dx = arc.x - ship.x,
    dy = arc.y - ship.y;

ctx.rotate( -ship.rot );

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo( 0, 0 );
ctx.arc( 0, 0, arc.r, arc.sRot, arc.eRot );

if( ctx.isPointInPath( dx, dy ) ||
    ctx.isPointInPath( dx + rect.w, dy ) ||
    ctx.isPointInPath( dx, dy + rect.h ) ||
    ctx.isPointInPath( dx + rect.w, dy + rect.h ) )

    collisionIsTrue();
```

Comment: I don't understand how your code works for his 1st image, none of the rectangle extremities are in the sector but they still intersect

Comment: @crl it does not. The main problem is to get the rectangle to be axis-aligned with the system to get the calculations to be easier, then which collision algo you choose to use is up to you. In his particular case a vertices-in-shape checking was good enough ;)

Comment: @towc: I can't get your test to work. :-// For example, if ship.y=200 then your test should report `false`, but it incorrectly returns `true`. Maybe I'm missing something:  https://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/ncyuh28r/